# How could I get the first K element in scala Array?

Tags: scala

I want to get first K element in scala Array, in Python, I could use :

`arr[0:K]` to get the top K element of arr,

How could I do in scala?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array

Comment: One does it by reading the API documentation, as @MarekAdamek has pointed out. Seriously, at least review that - you'll struggle unnecessarily if you're not somewhat familiar with the collections API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
arr.take(k)
```

Comment: do you know how to take 2-4 elements? in python, we could use arr[1:3]